# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare anp_realip() (previously declared in E_COMPILE_ERROR Error in file

Tags: php

Why is this given this error?
the error is
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare anp_realip() (previously declared in cr.php:196) in cr.php on line 219 E_COMPILE_ERROR Error in file �cr.php� at line 219: Cannot redeclare anp_realip() (previously declared in cr.php:196)

I included the file twice, thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have a file called cr.php ?

Comment: yes, the function is located in that file, you want me to paste all code from that file?

Comment: Check the line 219 and 196

Comment: as stated above, the lines are line 196 is $ip = FALSE; line 219 is the ending } of the function (the last one). I have no idea what to look for.

Comment: Change the name function, and see what change.

Comment: blank page, no errors, but the redirect is not working

Comment: That is another problem, try to figure out and make sure to change the occurence that was calling this specific function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes happen when you `require` or `include` the same file twice. Switch to `require_once` and/or `include_once` (these only require/include a file if it hasn't already been required/included).

It's possible that you're loading this file twice and, in the second time it's loaded, PHP complains that this function has already been defined.

Comment: I know and understand that, but what is included twice? The error is for $ip=false; how can that be included twice?

Comment: yes, cr.php was included twice and I did not see that, thank you very much.